# Usando entrada e saída padrão no Android

Tags: android, console

Quando aprendi a programar em Java usava muito a entrada e saída padrão (stdin e stdout). Agora que tenho curiosidade em aprender o que posso fazer no Android, queria saber se por questão de praticidade posso fazer o mesmo que fazia na plataforma Java SE, que é: criar um aplicativo "console".

Com um aplicativo console nós podemos fazer coisas bem práticas como por exemplo:

Direcionar a saída do programa para outros utilitários Unix (no Android requer o Busybox).

```
am start -n com.example.android/.MainActivity | sort -u | sed ... > saída.txt
```

Ou então direcionar a saída de outros programas para entrada padrão do meu programa.

```
logcat|am start -n com.example.android/.MainActivity
```

Cheguei a experimentar o Jackpal Terminal Emulator e percebi que ele usa estes recursos:

> Android absolutely supports pipes as well as unix domain sockets. Use
>   of exec is somewhat discouraged, but works at the moment.
>
> See the source of any android terminal emulator with a local shell
>   option for an example of how to do it. Essentially your gui just
>   replaces the terminal emulator, and your engine replaces the shell.
>   [Chris Stratton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3775510/3697611)

## Ver também

- [Redirecting STDIN and STDOUT of C program in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23352592/3697611)
- [Console input cannot be read when c++ Android NDK app is build as executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27842695/3697611)
- [How to run a specific Android app using Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5494891/3697611)

Comment: Mas usando o AndroidStudio ou AndroidEclipse os `System.out.print` mostra no terminal do proprio IDE a saida pra você depurar e se você estiver com o cabo ligado do celular e os drivers devidamente instalado para o aparelho você poderá instalar seu app em desenvolvimento diretamente no celular e a saida irá voltar para o IDE, mesmo que rodando no celular. Outra coisa o ADT tem emulador. -- Pra ser sincero não entendi a sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pela observação @GuilhermeNascimento, então, disso eu já estou consciente. Mas por exemplo, seu eu sair com meu Smartphone, estiver na rua e quiser deixar um aplicativo rondando no background e também quiser ver sua saída? Queria uma sugestão em como posso visualizar logs no próprio Smartphone.

Comment: então você teria que criar um campo de texto no proprio app e trocar `System.out` por um método de append no textfield e o background rodaria em um trhead

Comment: se eu aceito uma resposta outros ainda podem responder ou eu tenho que desmarcar a resposta? @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @guiwp uma pergunta pode ter inumeras respostas, porém, somente uma aceita. E isso não impede que outros continuem postando respostas.  Mas no caso desta, não é possivel mais responder, pois foi fechada como pendente. Veja as orientações no quadro amarelo e, se já tiver feito as alterações solicitadas, aguarde até que a mesma seja reaberta.

Comment: Obrigado @DiegoF, fiz as alterações esclarecendo melhor minha pergunta colocando mais detalhes e inclusive mudando o título da pergunta. Tudo para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Outros podem responder sim, mesmo que já tenha uma resposta aceita, todavia eu discordo da sua edição, quando for assim faça uma nova pergunta. Vou fazer um rollback porque você mudou o contexto do que foi perguntando.

Comment: DiegoF, @GuilhermeNascimento, se vcs quiserem eu solicito que remova essa pergunta para que eu possa fazer outra com mais detalhes (não hoje, outro dia)! De qualquer forma muito obrigado, estou aprendendo a mexer nisso daqui! abraço!

Comment: Não precisa remover pra fazer uma nova pergunta, entenda que o contexto daqui foi respondido, basta fazer uma nova como se fosse sequencia desta. Eu mesmo faço várias perguntas, teve algumas sobre [tag:ngnix] que eram uma sequencia de necessidade da outra, claro que você pode editar. Só uma dica, não somos um fórum, somo uma Q&A ;)

Comment: Gostei dessa "não somos um fórum, somo uma Q&A ;)" kkkk. Tudo ok amigo, espero entender melhor esse negocio aqui para não da trabalho para vcs!

Comment: Reverti a pergunta para o original e pra você não ter trabalho aqui esta o seu texto pra fazer uma nova pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/125795/5

Comment: hoje dei uma olhada sobre o assunto e aprendi coisas novas e resolvi compartilhar atualizando o corpo do texto

Answer (score 2):

Conforme o [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8708357/1518921) uma maneira de pegar os dados do console seria:

```
// Create a stream to hold the output
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);

// IMPORTANT: Save the old System.out!
PrintStream old = System.out;

// Tell Java to use your special stream
System.setOut(ps);

System.out.println("Foofoofoo!");
// Put things back
System.out.flush();
System.setOut(old);

baos.toString(); //Pega os dados
```

Depois pegue esse `baos.toString();` e coloque em um TextField ou similar.

Também pode-se trocar `System.out.print` por uma função própria que faria um append no TextField.

Comment: Parece uma alternativa interessante, vou estudá-la.